# Quick Way to sync directories on home and work PC

Tags: linux, sync

I am looking for a good tool for the following workflow:

I have a directory (~500MB) of different projects. Website Code, C applications, django applications, small virtual machines, imagery, etc. This directory currently lives on a laptop that I use for basically anything computer-related, and when I go to work (student assistant at university) I usually take this laptop with me and set it up there.

Now, however, I am going to get a PC for my work there, which means I won't need to carry my laptop around, but I need some way of syncing my work between the two machines.
Basically, I will never have both machines running at once, so the simplest workflow I can think of would be:

- every time I start one of the machines, it should pull the latest version
- every time I stop one of the machiens, it pushes its version as latest

where "push" and "pull" are some black-box processes of accessing a remote data store.

Currently, I implemented this using an `lftp mirror --reverse --delete` to a webhosting, but it's horribly slow. Are there any better solutions that I am just not aware of?

**UPDATE:**
While it's still too slow, I managed to considerably speed up the sync via the --parallel flag of lftp.

here is my call for the "push" process:

```
lftp -e '
  set ftp:sync-mode off
  open $HOST
  user $USER $PASS
  mirror --reverse --delete --verbose --parallel $SOURCE $TARGET
  bye'
```

Comment: Git Annex maybe?  http://git-annex.branchable.com/

Answer (score 1):

### Rsync

This seems like the use case for rsync. Homepage: http://rsync.samba.org/

From the [man page](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html):

> #### Description
>
> Rsync is a fast and extraordinarily versatile file copying tool. It can copy locally, to/from another host over any remote shell, or to/from a remote rsync daemon. It offers a large number of options that control every aspect of its behavior and permit very flexible specification of the set of files to be copied. It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination. Rsync is widely used for backups and mirroring and as an improved copy command for everyday use.
>
> Rsync finds files that need to be transferred using a "quick check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size or in last-modified time. Any changes in the other preserved attributes (as requested by options) are made on the destination file directly when the quick check indicates that the file's data does not need to be updated.
>
> Some of the additional features of rsync are:
>
> - support for copying links, devices, owners, groups, and permissions
> - exclude and exclude-from options similar to GNU tar
> - a CVS exclude mode for ignoring the same files that CVS would ignore
> - can use any transparent remote shell, including ssh or rsh
> - does not require super-user privileges
> - pipelining of file transfers to minimize latency costs
> - support for anonymous or authenticated rsync daemons (ideal for mirroring)

An example of a rsync would be:

```
rsync -avz user@host:'/src/' /dst
```

Some Gotcha's to look out for are the following:

- Be aware of trailing '/' makes a difference. The following two are the same

  - rsync -avz /src  /dst
  - rsync -avz /src/ /dst/src
- You must be careful with files with spaces so they are not expanded when the copy is run on remote shell.

  - rsync -avz user@host:'/src/this is bad' /dst
  - rsync -avz user@host:"'/src/this is good'" /dst
  - rsync -avz user@host:'/src/this\ is\ ok\ too' /dst

You either need to have a ssh daemon for remote copies or run rsync in daemon mode on remote computer.

First transfer will take awhile, but subsequent copies should be faster because it will only copy files that have changed in size.

It is also helpful to use filter rules if you want to skip certain types of files or directories.

Comment: I would love to use rsync, but I have no shell on the remote server.

Comment: As long as one of your computers, home or work can be public reachable you would not need a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

why not use dropbox or skydrive. similar apps like that. 500M is not a lot these days especially when everything is moving to fibre optics.

Comment: I would like to avoid cloud storage, mainly to have control over the remote storage I am accessing.